# storing multiple comlex metadata values in CRX i.e. xmpDM:markers

Tags: metadata, aem, xmp, crx, dam

I'm trying to store multiple complex metadata values in CQ CRX (Adobe DAM). The multiple simple metadata values are simply multi value properties in assets metadata node. The complex metadata values are subnodes of assets metadata node. But how about multiple complex metadata values like in example below? I can't find any example in CRX (JCR). (Maybe i should wrap marker metadata with rdf tags?)

```
<xmpDM:markers>
  <xmpDM:marker> 
     <xmpDM:name>name01</xmpDM:name>
     <xmpDM:startTime>18645250f44100</xmpDM:startTime>
     <xmpDM:duration>1000</xmpDM:duration>
  </xmpDM:marker>
  <xmpDM:marker> 
     <xmpDM:name>name02</xmpDM:name>
     <xmpDM:startTime>18645250f44101</xmpDM:startTime>
     <xmpDM:duration>1000</xmpDM:duration>
  </xmpDM:marker>
</xmpDM:markers>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to store the serialized xmpDm:marker elements as elements of a multivalue field.
But it has the drawback that you can not adress an xmpDm:marker's properties directly within a query.

Personally I would create a marker subnode for each marker element below the asset's metadata node and create a subnode for each of the the xmpDm:marker child elements. Each subnodes then contains the properties of it's corresponding xmpDm:marker element.

This can be done very easily as follows:

```
//given you have the content resource of your asset
Resource metaData = assetResource.getChild(DamConstants.METADATA_FOLDER);
Node node = metaData.adaptTo(Node.class);

// assume your already transformed your xml nodes into a list of marker objects
for(Marker marker : markers){
  Node markerNode = node.addNode(marker.getName());
  node.setProperty( ....)
}
```

Comment: So then where to save that the markerNode is xmpDM:marker type? I guess it will be nt:unstructured node? An how is marked that the markers are part of xmpDM:markers not xmpDM:Tracks?

Comment: By default CQ will create an nt:unstructured node as long as you do not tell it to take a different nodetype. Reflecting the sematics of the xmp spec on repository level would require you to setup up a namespace and node definitions for that. See http://jackrabbit.apache.org/node-type-notation.html
This allows you to bind relations and constraints to your model on repository level.
The other option (and my prefered one) is to implemement your constraints on application level and to use nt:unstructurd to store the data. It makes your life easier by experience.

Comment: I.e. the xmpDM namespace and tags is already defined in dam (/libs/dam/options/metadata/xmpMM, /libs/dam/nodetypes/dam.cnd), but there no such nodetypes. I wonder what is the proper way to reflect multiple complex metadata values so DAM could understand it.